# java's DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE

Tags: java

I have this snippet of the code:

```
public class Main_class {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame first = new JFrame();
        first.setTitle("Hello");
        first.setSize(300, 100);
        first.setLocation(300, 100);
        first.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        first.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I receive primitive frame, my question is how do I supposed to close the window without windows manager task, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *want* to close it anyways I would implement a close listener that disposes the frame:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final JFrame first = new JFrame();
    first.setTitle("Hello");
    first.setSize(300, 100);
    first.setLocation(300, 100);

    first.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

            // do other stuff....

            first.setVisible(false);
            first.dispose();
        }
    });

    first.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    first.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
first.setVisible(false);
first.dispose();
```

and if you want to terminate the application (including the dispatch thread)

```
System.exit(0);
```

should do the trick :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exit your program, then use:

```
 first.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

You can do this manually by calling `System.exit(0)`

Comment: But the title of the question is "java's DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE". Your answer is "use EXIT_ON_CLOSE"?

Comment: @aioobe - true, but the question also asks how to close the window without the task manager. Which lead me to believe that he might not know what the other options for the default close operation are (since he actually want to quit the app on close)

Answer (score 0):

In such cases (when you set the default close operation as `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`) a button is provided in the GUI clicking which will do the cleanup and exit the program.

Comment: Aren't you mixing it up with `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`? Or have I misunderstood your answer?

Comment: @aioobe: `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` will close the application when you hit the close (x) button whereas `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` will do nothing. So you need to provide your own button to exit the application. That is what I meant in my answer.